# Opening .desktop file outside of desktop immediately logs out

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, scripts, .desktop

This is my first question with Ask Ubuntu, so I'd like to thank you in advance for your patience.

My situation is this:
I have a `*.desktop` file (which I wrote) that is supposed to execute a shell script.  My initial intent was to place this file in `~/.config/autostart` so that it would run automatically at startup; however, this causes Ubuntu to flash the desktop for a split second, then log me back out. I can double click the file on my desktop and it will launch the script like it's supposed to.  If I take the `*.desktop` file out of the `~/Desktop` directory and put it literally anywhere else, double clicking it in Nautilus will also result in me being logged out immediately.

The `*.desktop` file is set to execute a shell script which starts `bash` in `gnome-terminal`.  My reasons for doing this are not necessarily important, so please assume that that's the way I need it to be.  If I add `sleep 10` to the beginning of the first shell script, I am logged out 10 seconds after starting the `*.desktop` file, regardless of how it is started.  It seems like the problem is in the fact that a new `gnome-terminal` window is started from the second script, but I don't understand how or why this would be.
Desktop entry:

```
[Desktop entry]
Name=Autocapture
Comment=Starts autocap program
Exec=/Autocapture/Startup/InitSystem
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

InitSystem:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup gnome-terminal --title=Autocapture --maximize -e "bash -c 'bash /Autocapture/Startup/StartAutocap.sh';bash"
wmctrl -a "Autocapture"           # Give focus to new terminal window
kill -9 $PPID                     # Close this terminal
```

StartAutocap.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon Autocap
python /path/to/python/module.py
```

This is supposed to (and successfully does, if launched from desktop) start a fullscreen `gnome-terminal` window running `bash` and launch the "`module.py`" program in that bash session.  It also closes the first `gnome-terminal` window that started and detached the child process.

Sorry for the incredibly long first post. I just want to understand what is going wrong here and how I might be able to fix it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

While I have my theories, I am afraid to proclaim that I know exactly (or even remotely) how or why this works.  I would imagine that it has something to do with the way a `*.desktop` launcher executes its target. Perhaps I was trying to kill the gnome-terminal window after it had already been closed at the end of the script's execution and ended up killing my session?  Maybe vice versa?  I don't claim to know, but I would invite anyone who does to *please answer this question with your explanation* so that others may learn from my mistake.

Removing the line `kill -9 $PPID` solved the problem

If the script is executed from the `*.desktop` launcher, the initial `gnome-terminal` window will close, leaving the second.  If the script is executed from the command line (for example, `$ bash InitSystem`), the initial `gnome-terminal` window does not close.

Comment: I think when one terminal window is closed all the processeses connected to the other end of the terminal get the SIGHUP signal, which by default terminates the process.